# errno.h socket/connection error classification

Tags: linux, sockets

I'm using boost::asio on linux to send http request, using almost exactly this code [boost asio http](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp)

I want to catch exceptions and classify them using errno.h error codes to three groups

GROUP 1. errors occurred because of local host socket/connection.

GROUP 2. errors occurred because of local host or remote host or third party.

GROUP 3. errors occurred because of remote
host socket/connection.

[Error codes](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_2.html) + [errno.h define](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html)

What I managed to classify (Im not sure about it)

**GROUP 1**

```
#define ENETDOWN        100     /* Network is down */
#define ENETUNREACH     101     /* Network is unreachable */
#define ENETRESET       102     /* Network dropped connection because of reset */
```

**GROUP 2**

```
//Not sure.
```

**GROUP 3**

```
#define ETIMEDOUT       110     /* Connection timed out */
#define ECONNREFUSED    111     /* Connection refused */
#define EHOSTDOWN       112     /* Host is down */
#define EHOSTUNREACH    113     /* No route to host */
```

I hope you can help me find incorrect error codes in the groups or add error code i missed to the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group 2:

```
EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK
```

Group 3:

```
ECONNRESET
```